# WPF PasswordBox: How do I warn a user that Caps Lock is enabled?

Tags: .net, wpf, passwordbox

Does anyone know how to implement the standard bubble message that warns users whenever Caps Lock is enabled and a password control has focus?  Is this built into the .NET framework, or do I need to write my own class to do this?

Comment: Did you solve this? I was looking for the same?

Comment: Follow:

[How to give warning to user with balloon in wpf][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092808/wpf-warn-about-capslock/8060520#8060520

Comment: Use Keyboard.IsKeyToggled for CapsLock key and manually show tooltip or hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a handler function to the [PasswordChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.passwordbox.passwordchanged.aspx) event handler and test for the value of the CapsLock key in that function. If found to be on, you could pop-up a message from there.

Comment: This will do the trick!  To detect CapsLock in the event handler, just check the boolean value of: Keyboard.IsKeyToggled(Key.CapsLock)

Comment: This answer is useless:
1. PasswordChanged happen TOO LATE. Much better to react on 'GotFocus'.
2. HOW EXACTLY we can check status of CapsLock key? That was the question.

Answer (score 12):

This is an old question, and already answered, but I came across this same problem and I first started with `Keyboard.IsKeyToggled(Key.CapsLock)` but that returned `false` if Caps Lock was set prior to the application running. So I found another solution that works perfectly.

```
Console.CapsLock //is boolean and returns true if CapsLock is on
```

Absolutely brilliant and simple (it's in the mscorlib dll so you don't have to worry about unneeded dependencies either)

Comment: It's wrong solution. You had to use Keyboard.IsKeyToggled

Answer (score 2):

If you use a MaskedTextBox and specify a passwordChar the .NET framework will automatically do this for you

Comment: I believe MaskedTextBox is a WinForms control - I'm using WPF.  I'd like to be able to continue using the PasswordBox because of its built-in security.