# Balloon Popup WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, popup, tooltip, popup-balloons

I need to display a baloon popup. Is there a control in WPF for this kind of work?
Something like the following:

```
<BalloonPopup>
   <StackPanel>
      <Button/>
      . . .
   </StackPanel>
</BalloonPopup>
```

This is the possible result:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement Balloon message in a WPF application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310102/how-to-implement-balloon-message-in-a-wpf-application)

Comment: @ReedCopsey no answers in your link...

Comment: There actually are - all of them are valid, but there is an accepted answer there, too (it's just not listed first, as it's the OP's solution)

Comment: @ReedCopsey but it is not the answer to the question, that answer does not explains how to do a balloon popup, have you tried it?

Answer (score 2):

You want to do a [tooltip](http://wpf.2000things.com/?s=tooltip).  wpf.200things has a great write on on it.

From this [article](http://wpf.2000things.com/2011/08/30/375-binding-something-in-a-tooltip-to-a-property-on-the-parent-control/).  You are basically going to style the tooltip like below

```
<TextBox Text="Now is the winter of our discontent etc"
    Width="100" Margin="10">
    <TextBox.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}">
            <StackPanel>
                <Label FontWeight="Bold" Content="Full Text"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding Text}"/>
                <Label Content="--Gloster, in Richard III (Act I, Scene I)"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ToolTip>
    </TextBox.ToolTip> </TextBox>
```

Comment: your tooltip is rectangular, i need a **balloon**.

Comment: @Nick You can style it to be what you want.  What I was showing you is how you could do it. With the ToolTip content you can make it anything you want, a picture if you want.

Comment: @Nick The ToolTip can be styled to look however you want. In your case, you'll probably need a `Path` element to draw the balloon outline in the shape you're looking for, and possibly a drop shadow effect.

Answer (score 1):

Dont know if you saw this but here you can find some pretty nice examples, that helped me in the same situation.

[How to implement Balloon message in a WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310102/how-to-implement-balloon-message-in-a-wpf-application)