# Where are tooltip balloons in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, balloon

In WinForms you used to be able to do this:

```
ToolTip hint = new ToolTip();
hint.IsBalloon = true;
```

as described here: [How to show a .NET Balloon ToolTip?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8716917/1742551) to display a balloon, as described by Microsoft here:    https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn742400.aspx

Where is this functionality in WPF? I can find lots of people detailing how they wrote their own, but where has this functionality gone?

EDIT:

I understand that there are questions out there on how to write your own or what code is available, but I'm asking - does anyone know why this functionality is recommended by Microsoft yet not included in what is meant to be their recommended UI language (WPF)?

Comment: Maybe you find something in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541767/how-can-i-show-a-balloon-tip-over-a-textbox or http://wpfplayground.com/category/balloon/

Comment: Linked duplicate answer does not answer this question. The linked question is how to implement a balloon message in WPF. This question is decidedly **not** asking how to implement a balloon message in WPF. This question is where is the built-in WPF control.

Answer (score 0):

There are some libraries out there that can help you. The other answers are correct though, WPF can be styled to look like whatever you want, the principle is the same though.

Check out https://toastspopuphelpballoon.codeplex.com/ for a library that does balloon pop-ups on WPF.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the tutorial [here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/ToolTip.html).

```
<Button Content="Submit">
    <Button.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">Submit Request</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock>Submits the request to the server.</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </ToolTip>
    </Button.ToolTip>
</Button>
```

You can then use typical wpf binding to bind the textblock control data to properties on your viewmodels (if you are using mvvm) if you would like.

Comment: No - I'm not after standard tooltips, I'm after BALLOON tooltips, as described in my question and in the links I included.

Comment: As mentioned in another post, you can style a tooltip however you would like to achieve the intended effect.  See the post here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/12499234/306894