# Trying to pass validation to my custom tooltip control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, tooltip

I am trying to make a custom tooltip control that is used for TextBoxes.

It will look like this:

[image]

...except for some pixels that comes from the background components that I have gimped away as good as possible.

The idea comes from:
[How to implement Balloon message in a WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310102/how-to-implement-balloon-message-in-a-wpf-application)

The problem is that the code behind of my custom control never gets the validation object (that should be passed to it via the trigger in generic.xaml).

Why not?

generic.xaml:

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Name="tb">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="200" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource InputBackgroundColor}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource InputBorderBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0,0,5" />
    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip">
          <Setter.Value>
            <Windows:ValidationBalloonPopupWindow
              Validation="{Binding Path=Validation, ElementName=tb}" />
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
```

As you see, I try to refer to Validation by using ElementName of tb.
Seems like Name is not used in templates. If I change to x:Key instead, all my textboxes becomes like 10 pixels wide. Probably not the right thing to do in other words.

The code behind, ValidationBalloonPopupWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Foo.ToolTips
{
    public partial class ValidationBalloonPopupWindow : ToolTip
    {
        public ValidationBalloonPopupWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }    

        public static DependencyProperty ValidationProperty
            = DependencyProperty.Register("Validation", typeof(object), typeof(ValidationBalloonPopupWindow),
                new PropertyMetadata(null, OnChangedValidationByBinding));

        private static void OnChangedValidationByBinding
            (DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((ValidationBalloonPopupWindow)d).OnChangedValidationByBinding(e.NewValue);
        }
        public void OnChangedValidationByBinding(object newValue)
        {
            txtMessage.Text = newValue.GetType().Name;
        }

        private object _validation;
        public object Validation
        {
            get
            {
                return _validation;
            }
            set
            {
                _validation = value;
                txtMessage.Text = _validation.GetType().Name;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which has a setter that should run, I have tried to put a lot of breakpoints in this file without success.

The xaml for the control itself, ValidationBalloonPopupWindow.xaml:

```
<ToolTip x:Class="FRAM.Windows.ValidationBalloonPopupWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" HasDropShadow="false"
    Placement="Bottom"
    Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
  <Grid Height="126" Width="453">
    <Border Margin="7,13,0,0"
          CornerRadius="10,10,10,10" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="429" Height="82" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.RowSpan="2">
      <Border.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect Color="#FF474747" />
      </Border.Effect>
      <Border.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
          <GradientStop Color="#FF58C2FF" Offset="0" />
          <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
      </Border.Background>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Label Content="Title" Height="31" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Margin="12,8,0,0" Name="lblCaption" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" />
        <TextBlock Margin="18,0,0,0" Name="txtMessage" Width="378" HorizontalAlignment="Left">Body</TextBlock>
      </StackPanel>
    </Border>
    <Path Data="M25,25L10.9919,0.64 0.7,25" Fill="#FF58C2FF" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
      Margin="32,3,0,0" Stretch="Fill" Width="22" Height="10" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
  </Grid>
</ToolTip>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of referring by name, get the Textbox itself by using `RelativeSource` binding.
Try something like this:

```
<Setter Property="ToolTip">
    <Setter.Value>
       <Windows:ValidationBalloonPopupWindow
           Validation="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Validation}" />
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```