# How can I disable the Caps Lock warning with a password control?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I get this when I have Caps Lock on with a password control in focus. I would like to add my own warning instead. How can I disable this one? I don't mind P/Invoke or any native code but it has to be in C#.

[image]

Comment: would @M. Nasser Javaid answer to a related topic help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092808/warn-about-capslock

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your form, override WndProc like so, which will intercept the EM_SHOWBALOONTIP message and prevent the control from receiving it:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
  if (m.Msg != 0x1503) //EM_SHOWBALOONTIP
     base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me, on the `KeyDown` event of a `TextBox`:

```
    private void txtPassword_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.CapsLock)
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you notice the question is in English? Does it help to post an answer in another language?